# request to prohibit anonymous and without-reason-explanation downvoting

Tags: feature-request, reputation

More than half of my posts has downvoting without any comments.

I believe that downvoting without explaining the reasons, as well as anonymous downvoting, should be prohibited.

What is the sense of seeing my questions or answers anonymously or unreasonably downvoted?

I think enormous amount of new-coming professionals are repelled from the site by it.

I believe that moderators should monitor repelling-activists and apply publicly viewable measures against them...

---

--------- **Update1**

**@MarkM**,

> Perhaps you should look at the half of
>   your posts that have been downvoted
>   and do have comments. Chances are,
>   people are sick of repeating
>   themselves.

What do you mean that I have not looked into what I had written? It is a waste of time to argue with you about manners or even read your posts.

What is the point in upvoting incorrect answers and downvoting, for ex., in

- [How to back up a MSSQL Database](https://serverfault.com/questions/170195/how-to-back-up-a-mssql-database)

or even deleting, for ex., like it was with with my answer in

- [Windows Server 2008 - Connecting to 127.0.0.1](https://serverfault.com/questions/170476/windows-server-2008-connecting-to-127-0-0-1/)

the correct answers or useful discussions?

Should I extend the list?

---

--------- **Update2**

**@Zoredache**,

you are also in my list of spammers and abusers. The guy who closed half a dozen of my questions and deleted the only (my) answer in

- [Windows Server 2008 - Connecting to 127.0.0.1](https://serverfault.com/questions/170476/windows-server-2008-connecting-to-127-0-0-1/)

which was recognized by answerer as answer...

Comment: -1, worthless comment. (see, this is why)

Comment: Zordache isn't a moderator, so he cannot unilaterally close questions and he cannot delete answers at all. Closing a question requires 5 votes from people over 3k reputation.

Comment: Good god.  Can we please stop feeding the troll?

Comment: I've voted to close this as pointless noise and can only wonder why others haven't done likewise. This person just keeps posting minor variations of the same thing. Meta should not become his/her personal gripe area.

Answer (score 5):

This ground has slready been covered.

- [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)
- [Allow users to leave an anonymous comment when voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/leaving-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting)

It will not help.  Basically, people would just post comments that are worthless.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should look at the half of your posts that have been downvoted and do have comments. Chances are, people are sick of repeating themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The few posts of yours I've seen have often been poorly thought out rambling messes, especially with your habit of adding great long lists of "---Update x---" type edits to the answer, half of which might be responding to subsequent facts and clarifications in the question and comments, and half of which might be comments on people you think have down-voted you. Please don't tell me you think that makes your answers easy to read, understand or put to use.

You often appear more interested in picking an argument over whether or not something is correct than in actually spending the time to research it and learn something one way or another.

Your comment about MarkM in response to his reply really sums this up quite nicely - He's got nearly 4500 reputation here, so its fair to say that quite a few people don't agree with your suggestion that it's a waste of time to read his posts.

You've mentioned a few times that you post answers in order to learn - well that's great but speaking for myself, I *read* answers in order to find an answer to a problem first of all, and answers which don't even appear to try to answer the question properly are not helpful to the person who asked the question or to others trying to use the questions and answers to research a problem.

Answers that poor deserve to be down-voted (I've had a few down-votes when I've given really poor answers out and they've been deserved). If you keep answering questions in the same way and they keep getting down-voted then maybe you should consider changing your approach.