# Is there anyway to filter out certain users' comments, questions, answers?

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed a fair bit of noise from one user on the Parent and Meta site, is there anyway to filter out users "contributions", similar to how we can filter tags?

I suspect this one user will go away, eventually, but fear that another user will just take their place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag, flag, flag - it's like a red-hot poker when we log in.  ;)  This most recent episode is on me, I should've given up on coaxing and suspended that user a couple of days beforehand.

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/680/quotas-on-downvoting/687#687 appears to have been posted after the suspension. Am I reading things wrong or has the suspension not prevented the post?

Comment: He was banned on the main site before meta.  meta was a day about 14 hours later.

Comment: I've read all the comments in the MSO links, I can see how flagging is more useful.  Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Treat the disease, not the symptoms, is my advice here.

If a user is so disruptive that you "need" a killfile, the problem isn't the lack of the feature.. but insufficient moderation.

Comment: I think you underestimate the power of trolls that be trollin' hard. I never ever edit noise out of people's answers for fear or changing their meaning by accident, but in vgv8's case (which I assume this is about), most of his posts have over a dozen edits and rollbacks and even I've gotten in on the action. He's a super troll, a new breed never before seen.

Comment: The Internet has seen every sort of troll many years before now.  Different medium, similar methods.  Agreed, Jeff.  While I see the benefit of an ignore feature, it is not something typically applied to this type of medium.

Comment: @Warner - I was half joking and I don't support an ignore feature, my point, which I guess was poorly articulated, was that this guy annoying people isn't the fault of the mods. They appeared to do everything they could (as well as other community members) leading up to the ban.

Comment: I wouldn't use a killfile feature if we had one, because I WANT to see the trolls so I can help stomp on them. I ignore certain *tags* since I don't know diddly about them, but I'd even stop that if I were a full-up moderator.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way that I know of.  The noise level (like what you've seen over the past few days from one user) here isn't very consistent, so when it is, it stands out like a sore thumb and is dealt with pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I know how you feel. But this has been discussed on MSO, and so far this ability hasn't been added:

[Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users)

There is a possible way to implement your own killfile mentioned in one of the answers to that question.